# Card.io Android SDK size is too big

Tags: card.io

Is there any lightweight version of the card.io android sdk? Since its size is larger than my whole app. The SDK is 11Mb vs 9Mb of my app. It ends up being larger than 20Mb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, card.io is big because card scanning is not trivial.  You're welcome to excluse all the `*.so` files if you just want a manual entry form.  [Example documentation of this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/#disabling-cardio-card-scanning) is found in the PayPal Android SDK

Comment: I tried using above example in gradle but still apk size is big. I double checked it by unzipping apk file to check for so files and they are in lib folders

Answer (score 0):

You may be happy because iOS version is a way bigger.

After including this Framework, a source code is about 300 MB larger, but a whole application's build (IPA file) is let's say, only an about 30 MB in total.